# Do I really need to care if my car burns oil?

Tags: oil, mazda, lantis-323

My car, a 97 Mazda 323, burns about a liter of oil per 1000 kilometers, mostly start and stop city driving.  Sometimes I see a puff on start-up and sometimes I see smoke while accelerating, but it's intermittent. So I figure that both the valve seals and the oil rings are probably worn ( even though the car supposedly had a head job about four or five years ago).

My question is, to what extent does this really matter, beyond the cost of the oil burned?

Comment: Beyond the cost of the oil burned and the unneeded pollution?

Comment: @Hennes Yes, beyond the cost of the oil burned, is there some other issue that I should be concerned with, i.e. something which will cost me money?

Comment: Typo in title: "Do I really need to car"?  Do you mean "care"?

Comment: If you have emissions testing in your area, a car that burns oil is probably likely to fail it.  So at some point you may have no choice but to get it fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said "valve gaskets" but I'm going to assume you actually mean the *valve seals*. Since you are seeing a small puff of smoke sometimes during startup and when you are accelerating, these are usually caused by two separate issues, both of which you are mentioning.

Start-up puff of smoke can usually be attributed to bad valve seals. This is because oil will leak past them after engine shutdown. It then either pools on the back of the valves (if closed) or drips down past the valves onto the piston (if closed). When you start up the car, the oil burns off and causes the puff of smoke.

Smoke on acceleration can usually be attributed worn oil control rings not doing their job and allowing oil to pass by them and into the combustion chamber.

One of the issues which you could be causing is that the oil will eventually plug your catalytic converter (if it's still installed).

Comment: Any issue other than a potential long term effect on the cat?  Any significant effect on fuel efficiency for example?

Comment: In and of itself, I don't think that burning oil is going to cause a loss of fuel mileage ... at first. As it starts to coat the spark plugs, these will lose efficiency, so fuel mileage will go down. Also, as the cat starts to plug, you'll get less and less usable power, which will affect gas mileage as well as how fast the vehicle will go. If you continue to use the vehicle after the the cat is plugging up, you run the risk of damaging the head from over pressure/heat. It's a slow downward spiral, nothing which will happen overnight, but it *will happen*.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this same question to the workshop that performed the headjob on one of my cars and they said that apart from a bit of smoke, it wouldn't be anything to worry about. As long as there is enough oil in the engine. They could have told me to give them more money, but they didn't.